# Xlib: extension "GLX" missing on display ":0". Asus k53s

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I had everything working fine, I use a number of openGL graphics software, example pymol, mgltools, vmd, ballview, rasmol etc.

All of these give the error:

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

and fail to initialize.

I have an i7 asus k53s with nvidia gforce

I need these to do my work.  I tried the umblebee fix, and just removing all nvidia drivers, or rolling back.  I do not know why these were working then stopped, but did notice a new nvidia console in the mu which I assume was from enabling the automatic nvidia feeds, etc?  I also played with the xorg, however have no clue what settings are valid.  In addition, the display is 50% of the time not recognized now?  It just gives a geeic 640x480 and I have to login and out 10 times to get it to return to a normal setting.  When I try and set it manual, there is no other setting allowed from the settings menus, and the terminal changes just get re set every time I log out?

Answer (score 1):

Completely disabling the Nvidia GPU , then installing bumblebee, plus mesa glx and gl libraries worked, however now I have a GPU which is useless.  Thus, if anyone has a fix that allows use of the GPU, even if for other applications such as GPU accelerated software (CUDA or OpenCL) , or some graphics based applications.  Otherwise it seems pointless to even have a Gforce on the PC, when everything seems to work perfect with ATI software, and now synaptic available openCL headers, etc...